# Display Loading dots in a message box object

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a permanent message box in my windows forms application. Not to be confused with a pop up message box. The box I have displays text based on various buttons pushed in the application to update the user on whats happening. I successfully use the code below to display text in the box.

```
messageBox.Text += "I stick message in here" + Environment.NewLine;
```

I am interested in displaying some blinking dots in the box to indicate that something is coming. eg. "Finding stuff..."

I have found this code for Console.Write below.
How can I make this work in my message box

```
for (int dots = 0; dots <= 3; ++dots)
   {
      Console.Write("\rStuff will come{0}", new string('.', dots));
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500); // half a sec
   }
```

Comment: why not create a string variable that you can use across the application for example `public static string dots = new string('.',3);` then write `Console.Write(string.Format("\r Stuff will come{0}", dots));`

Comment: You may be interested in [ProgressBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.progressbar.aspx)

Comment: change this line  Console.Write("\rStuff will come{0}", new string('.', dots)); to 
`Console.Write("Stuff will come{0} \r", new string('.', dots));` since you're in a loop you really don't need this line `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);`

Comment: yah I was way over thinking this. I changed `Console.Write("\rStuff will come{0}", new string('.', dots));`    to `messageBox.Text += (string.Format("."));` and all is good.  You led me in the right direction DJ KRAZE

Answer (score 0):

I've solved a similar problem using a [Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx). One Task to do the background work and one to update the message text. Here is some sample code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // call the helper to do something
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { FakeSearch(); });
    //Generate the update the waiting text
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { updateWaiting(); });
}

private void FakeSearch()
{
    _externalFlag = false;
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    _externalFlag = true; // simulate completing the task
}

private bool _externalFlag = false;
private void updateWaiting()
{
    int count = 0;
    StringBuilder waitingText = new StringBuilder();

    waitingText.Append("Finding stuff");
    int baseLen = waitingText.Length;

    while (!_externalFlag)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000); // time between adding dots
        if (count >= 3) // number of dots
        {
            waitingText.Remove(baseLen, count);
            count = 0;
        }
        waitingText.Append(".");
        count++;

        BeginInvoke(new Action( () => { updateText(waitingText.ToString()); }) );
    }
    BeginInvoke(new Action( () => { updateText("done"); }) );
}

private void updateText(string txt)
{
    textBox1.Text = txt;
}
```